# Copy text from mac to ipad

Tags: mac, ipad, text, apns, url

I'm often reading stuff on my Mac but then I want to switch to my iPad to read it there. Is there a simple way to copy text or an URL from my Mac to my iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy an URL you could try [Jumping URL](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id388521070) as well as [myPhoneDesktop](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id352226779) which can also push text to the Notes app on the iPad.  Let me know what you think about these.  In the meantime I'll look for some more apps.

Comment: I can't find the jumping URL but the myphonedesktop is what I'm looking for. Not sure it's gonna be worth the $5 ;-)

Comment: Oh, I think it's worth the 5 dollars.  You can push links, text, images, and calls from you desktop to your phone.  Also the desktop version is available on all platforms.  And, say you are using a friends computer, you can log in on their website and use the online version.

Answer (score 4):

Safari's reading list and iCloud works well to synchronize a list of URL between Macs and iOS devices. The [Simplenote app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simplenote/id289429962?mt=8) and [web app](http://simplenoteapp.com/) work well to let all your devices keep track of text documents. You only need to pay for the latter if you want enhanced features or avoid the advertisements that are minimal and generally very tasteful.

Answer (score 2):

[Pastebot](http://tapbots.com/software/pastebot/), while not iPad native, is excellent for pushing images/text and various other bits between a Mac and iOS device.

If you're looking for a longer lasting solution, check out [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com).

Answer (score 1):

A free no additional app solution exists If you are using iCloud, you can use the built in Notes Application on the iPhone / iPad and coming soon to Mac OS X via Mountain Lion.

But til then on Lion Notes can be oddly be accessed via the OS X Lion Mail Application Notes function.  You can copy paste to Notes and then grab results from whichever platform you wish.

[image: Mail.app Notes]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also try [NoteFile](http://notefileapp.com/) for iOS devices and the corresponding widget for Mac. It syncs beautifully between both almost instantly. It's made by junecloud.com

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, user20578! Thanks for posting an answer! Can you please provide a link to NoteFile? Thank you!